# Specify different Ruby versions (e.g. 1.9.3 vs 2.1) in Gemfile for Windows and Linux/OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, windows, rubygems

I'm on a Ruby on Rails project where we have Windows and Linux computers.  The project uses Ruby 2.1, but as a windows dev I need to use a lower version of Ruby like ruby 1.9.3 or Ruby 2.0 in order to smoothly do local dev work.

So to implement custom Ruby versions for my Rails project based on platform automatically, I tried to modify the Gemfile to segregate different Gems and Ruby Versions for each platform:

```
platforms :ruby do # linux & Mac only
  ruby '2.1.0' #doesn't work, still tries to load ruby 1.9.3
  gem 'puma', '~> 2.7.1' #works
end

platforms :mswin do #Windows only
  ruby '1.9.3' #doesn't work, overrides Linux/mac users to Ruby 1.9.3 rather than 2.1
  gem 'thin' # works
end
```

`platforms :ruby` or `platforms :mswin` apparently only works for designating Gems, and doesn't work for specifying Ruby versions.  How do I set up my local windows dev environment so that I can work on a lower/different Ruby version automatically within the same Gemfile without affecting my co-workers?

#### Note:

`.rubyversion` reads `2.1.0`  While I could `.gitignore` this file to specify for each environment, Heroku requires us to specify a Ruby version within the Gemfile--so we need some way to resolve this at the Gemfile level.

Comment: It's probably better to ship a `.ruby-version` file that's ignored by Windows than to go down this path. Using `rbenv` or `rvm`?

Comment: Have you tried using `if(RUBY_PLATFORM=~ /win32/) ruby '1.9.2' else  ruby '2.1.0' end`? Let me know if that at least stops Windows from overriding on Linux.

Comment: I typed `if(RUBY_PLATFORM=~ /win32/) ruby '1.9.2' else  ruby '2.1.0' end` exactly into my Gemfile but that didn't work--on windows it specifies the Gemfile as 2.1.0.  Is there something with the Path I'm referencing that would do this?  This solution seems like it would work.

Also, this project does have a `.ruby-version` set as `2.1.0`, but apparently they also need to define the Ruby version in the Gemfile for heroku.

Comment: I'm currently on using Railsinstaller with Ruby 1.9.3.  There's no RVM for windows (and PIK seems a bit out of date lately with no changes pushed for 2 to 3 years), so I'm thinking my best bet is to stick with Railsinstaller Ruby1.9.3 or Ruby 2.0.0 versions for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A Gemfile is a DSL implemented in Ruby, so you can just call Ruby code here:

```
ruby RUBY_PLATFROM =~ /win/ ? '1.9.2' : '2.1.0'
```